# Animating PNGs Images from display none to block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got around 10 images in which the next one is the same as before but with an added element. The images are flowers, the first one has no petals,the next one has one, then two, then three. I'm trying to animate the image as it fades In, to create the ilusion as if only the new petal faded in. This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        #animation img {
            display: none;
            -moz-animation-delay: 3.5s;
             -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
             -o-animation-delay: 3.5s;
              animation-delay: 3.5s;
        }
        #animation img:first-child {
            display: block;
            -moz-animation-delay: 3.5s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
   -o-animation-delay: 3.5s;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
        }
      </style>


      <script type = "text/javascript">
        function startAnimation() { 
            var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
            var frameCount = frames.length;
            var i = 0;
            setInterval(function () { 
                frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
                frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
            }, 3000);
        }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body onload="startAnimation()">
      <div id="animation">
        <img src="logo0.png" alt="My image" />
        <img src="logo1.png" alt="My image" /> 
        <img src="logo2.png" alt="My image" /> 
        <img src="logo3.png" alt="My image" /> 
        <img src="logo4.png" alt="My image" /> 
        <img src="logo5.png" alt="My image" /> 
        <img src="logo6.png" alt="My image" /> 
        <img src="logo7.png" alt="My image" /> 
        <img src="logo8.png" alt="My image" /> 
        <img src="logo9.png" alt="My image" /> 
        <img src="logo10.png" alt="My image" /> 
        <img src="logo_end.png" alt="My image" /> 
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `display` property is non-animatable. You could try using `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1` instead or use the jQuery `fadeIn()`/`fadeOut()` functions.

Comment: What is your question? What is your code not doing that you want us to help with?

Comment: I wanna know if the image can be animated as it appears, by instead of instantly appearing, fading in

Comment: Use position:absolute, give each image a z-index, an opacity of 0, then fade each one in, animating the opacity from 0 to 1...

Comment: You cannot animate the display property, but you can work with height and opacity, if you want I will post some css and/JS code as example.

Comment: a jsfiddle would be amazing